# Shape Keys are not working when dyntopo is used to change the mesh

Tags: sculpting

I was sculpting a shape which also needed to be animated. So I used dyntopo to stretch out a part of the model but the shape key is not working. I unchecked dyntopo and stretched out the mesh but its working then. So dyntopo feature not works with shapekeys?

Comment: Dyntopo generates geometry while brush paints over the mesh. Shapekeys work best with vertices of the original mesh, so no added / removed ones. Why would you use dyntopo for this?

Comment: I am new to the sculpting in Blender. I needed to stretch a portion of my mesh and I found the meshes are getting distorted, so I thought of using dyntopo (like dynamesh in Zbrush) for making more geometry.

Comment: Yes, but that won't work with shapekeys since their general limitation is "no new geometry to be added when shapekey is present". Find a different way to stretch the mesh or change the workflow, that's all that can be stated given the current details in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information